# Website or bookmarklet to get a screenshot of a webpage

Tags: webapp-rec, bookmarklet, screenshot

Is there a website or bookmarklet which given a URL will output a screenshot of that page?

Ideally there should be options to resize the outputted image.

Comment: a screenshot of what you are seeing right now (the current state of the dom) or just a screenshot of the website as it can be seen by others?

Comment: Both are good options, but the latter is what I'm more interested in.

Comment: https://blitapp.com is useful if you want scheduled screenshots emailed to you regularly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [Aviary](http://aviary.com/capture)

It's very simple: copy paste the url of the site and Aviary will load it up in its online image editor (see below)

They also have a Firefox addon and a bookmarklet, in which case it will fill in your current website for you (but on the same tab, so watch out!)

[image]

Comment: This looks like it does what I want, unfortunately every URL I give it doesn't work. It just says "Uh oh! We couldn't perform the capture."

Comment: I recommend giving the Chrome extension a shot, worked flawlessly for me

Comment: Voilva http://aviary.com/creation?fguid=b56caae0-d63f-102d-a9f3-0030488e168c

Answer (score 4):

It does not have any other options except making a screenshot but worth mentioning it:

http://browsershots.org/

For editing you can use then some of the [Online editing software](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/276/what-online-image-editing-image-manipulation-web-applications-exist-features)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted something which could capture screenshots of a local server, so a web service like Browsershots wasn't what I wanted.

Therefore, using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) I've made a bookmarklet which captures a screenshot locally, rendering elements with a canvas.

To use it, copy this as a bookmarklet:

```
(function(d,w,h,s,i){w[h]||(s=d.createElement('script'),s.src='//html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js',d.body.appendChild(s));i=setInterval(function(){w[h]&&clearInterval(i)||w[h](d.body,{onrendered:function(c){w.open().document.body.appendChild(c)}})},250)}(document,window,'html2canvas'));
```

Then, click on it and possibly allow the pop-up it creates (the pop-up contains the screenshot).

For example, on Chrome you have to click on the right-most part of the address bar like so:

[image: screenshot]

Then clicking on the link corresponding to the screenshot's pop-up to open it.

Comment: Hi, this bookmarklet is really useful, thanks for sharing. I intend to customize it according to my needs, was wondering why you put the 5 parameters inside the function and how do they get their values since the function is being called on clicking the bookmarklet without any parameters and those parameters names aren't likely to be defined in every webpage.

Comment: @Chirag64 I did it like this to save a few characters (I'm kind of a code-golf person), here's what happens: the `d`, `w` and `h` parameters get passed in the end (example: `(function(d){/* d is now an alias to document */}(document))`). The fourth and fifth parameters are just placeholders I've re-used later to save a couple characters on `var` declarations :) So I don't pollute the global scope while code-golfing it.

Comment: That's some good coding right there. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not a web app or bookmarklet, but what I use for this purpose is a Firefox plugin called [Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146/). I don't know if that's an option for you, but you can give it a try (if you're using Firefox, of course; and I'm sure there will be other similar ones for other browsers)

Answer (score 1):

> [GreenShot](http://getgreenshot.org/)

Try this software,a good piece of coding .

Just press PrintScreen on the keyboard -- a tool appears,and select the region of the screen shot, the image comes around !!

Comment: This is Windows software.  I changed the link from the .exe to the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the browshot API: https://browshot.com/api/documentation

You can specify any size for the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the web sites here, but they didn't work to well. Both Aviary and Browsershots were not pleasant to use. You should not use a webapp, but rather a browser extension for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a wordpress plugin that will automate the job for you than "Simple Website Screenshot" does a fantastic job. You can specify the thumbnail size etc.

http://www.digg-it.info/wordpress-simple-website-screenshot-v-0-5

We use it on our own website (http://productivewebapps.com) if you'd like to see an example of it in use! (Disclaimer: I am the owner of this site)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://snapito.com/extras) site is useful (with bookmarklet) or [this Firefox Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/abduction/) (not working on Retina).