# What web apps will produce thumbnail screenshots of modern web sites

Tags: webapp-rec, screenshot, thumbnail

I'm looking for a web app (ideally with an API) that will, when given a URL, take a screenshot of the web page and provide thumbnail images. It must support sites that use javascript for rendering, and modern standards particularly CSS3 and Web Fonts.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/582/website-or-bookmarklet-to-get-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage

Comment: Is was similar to that question, I've edited it to put more emphasis on the modern standards aspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with bluga.net's [WebThumbs](http://webthumb.bluga.net/home) service as it has the best support for the latest CSS3 modules that we're using, and a really easy to use but thorough API. The only thing significant that was missing was support for web fonts, which the author is already working on.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/) and choose a reasonable modern browser (this will include the browser window though). It even has an [XML-RPC API](http://browsershots.org/xmlrpc/).

Answer (score 0):

[Browshot](http://browshot.com/) uses real modern web browsers, with full HTML5/CSS3/Flash support. You can try the service for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a wordpress plugin that will automate the job for you than "Simple Website Screenshot" does a fantastic job. You can specify the thumbnail size etc.

http://www.digg-it.info/wordpress-simple-website-screenshot-v-0-5

We use it on our own website (http://productivewebapps.com) if you'd like to see an example of it in use! (Disclaimer: I am the owner of this site)